# Win 7 Task Scheduler Interactive Mode

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I would like to run a scheduled bat file every day on Win7 machines.
The file needs to launch IE interactively and crawl a list of web pages to generate web traffic.  I could achieve this with wget and it will generate the traffic, but I need IE to run interactively so it launches and generates the traffic through an IE plugin that tracks urls visited. The interactive

Need to run interactively when user is logged and or when not logged on
Every Day at 5am repeat for 12 hours
Problem is that IE wont launch.

bat file looks like this

start /d iexplore.exe http://www.google.com

ping 1.1.1.1 -w 5000 >NUL

start /d iexplore.exe http://www.yahoo.com

taskkill /im iexplore.exe

Comment: The IP `1.1.1.1` is now taken by CloudFlare, so this will not wait for 5s but return in some ms.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need the path of ie like this or it needs quotes ""

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://www.google.com